# Joining table inside view with that view SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have been given a task to import some SQL into an existing view. I have realised that this code joins with the view it needs to be added to.

Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer(view) Cust 
LEFT join (
select * from People p
Where id <> '') cu
on Cust.no = p.no
```

View code:

```
CREATE view Customer
as
SELECT * 
FROM Customer2(othertable) Cust2 
LEFT join (
select * from People p
Where id <> '') cu
on Cust(current view).no = p.no
```

Basically, its joining a table with the result of the view it is in. My initial thought would be to create this as a second view but my superiors want it in the same view. Is there anyway this can be done using sub queries or variables?

The view is huge so i have cut it down so hopefully it shows what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Why would you repeat the  same join to the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no need to use a subquery for the view:

```
CREATE VIEW Customer as
    SELECT . . .   -- you should list the columns explicitly  
    FROM Customer2 c2 LEFT JOIN
         People p
         ON p.id <> '' AND p.no = c2.no;
```

The code you have provided would just repeat the same join.  You can add another join easily enough:

```
    SELECT . . .   -- you should list the columns explicitly  
    FROM Customer2 c2 LEFT JOIN
         People p
         ON p.id <> '' AND p.no = c2.no LEFT JOIN
         othertable ot
         ON . . .
```

Comment: The reason it is sub queried is because there is other sub queries. Is there any way i can store the result of the view in a variable and then select from that in the same query? or is that just not SQL logic?

Comment: You can 'pre define' a number of select statements inside a view using `with` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql. This is handy to simplfy (and reuse parts of) a complicated view. Otherwise you can do it more procedurally using a stored proc or a table valued function, but you should probably avoid that